# Celery Received unregistered task of type (run example)

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to run [example](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#id3) from Celery documentation.

I run: `celeryd --loglevel=INFO`

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/loaders/default.py:64: NotConfigured: No 'celeryconfig' module found! Please make sure it exists and is available to Python.
  "is available to Python." % (configname, )))
[2012-03-19 04:26:34,899: WARNING/MainProcess]  

 -------------- celery@ubuntu v2.5.1
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- [Configuration]
-- * - **** ---   . broker:      amqp://guest@localhost:5672//
- ** ----------   . loader:      celery.loaders.default.Loader
- ** ----------   . logfile:     [stderr]@INFO
- ** ----------   . concurrency: 4
- ** ----------   . events:      OFF
- *** --- * ---   . beat:        OFF
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [Queues]
 --------------   . celery:      exchange:celery (direct) binding:celery
```

tasks.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from celery.task import task

@task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

run_task.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tasks import add
result = add.delay(4, 4)
print (result)
print (result.ready())
print (result.get())
```

In same folder celeryconfig.py:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", )
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 300
```

When I run "run_task.py":

on python console

```
eb503f77-b5fc-44e2-ac0b-91ce6ddbf153
False
```

errors on celeryd server

```
[2012-03-19 04:34:14,913: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'tasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
{'retries': 0, 'task': 'tasks.add', 'utc': False, 'args': (4, 4), 'expires': None, 'eta': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'id': '841bc21f-8124-436b-92f1-e3b62cafdfe7'}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 444, in receive_message
    self.strategies[name](message, body, message.ack_log_error)
KeyError: 'tasks.add'
```

Please explain what's the problem.

Comment: Hi, could you please share what the problem was and how you resolved? The accepted answer doesn't make it clear how others could solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'm with Jordan- this was not useful at all.  Downvoted.

Comment: the answer of aiho is the correct one: `CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", )`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can see the current list of registered tasks in the `celery.registry.TaskRegistry` class. Could be that your celeryconfig (in the current directory) is not in `PYTHONPATH` so celery can't find it and falls back to defaults. Simply specify it explicitly when starting celery.

```
celeryd --loglevel=INFO --settings=celeryconfig
```

You can also set `--loglevel=DEBUG` and you should probably see the problem immediately.

Comment: +1 for `--loglevel=DEBUG`,  there was a syntax error in my task.

Comment: celeryd is obsolete. Now one should run `celery worker` e.g for `Django` like this `celery --app=your_app.celery worker --loglevel=info`

Comment: For me (celery 3.1.23), I had to use `celery.registry.tasks` to see a list of all of my current tasks. You can always check by running `dir(celery.registry)`.

Comment: for `--loglevel=DEBUG` from my side as well

Answer (score 130):

Restart the worker server. I had the same problem and solved it by restarting.

Comment: This fixed it for me. If you're using celeryd scripts, the worker imports your task module(s) at startup. Even if you then create more task functions or alter existing ones, the worker will be using its in-memory copies as they were when it read them.

Comment: Note: you can verify that your tasks is or is not registered by running `celery inspect registered`

Comment: You also can start celery with option `--autoreload` which will restart celery each time code was changed.

Comment: Unfortunately deprecated. One could use a solution from this link: https://avilpage.com/2017/05/how-to-auto-reload-celery-workers-in-development.html

Answer (score 62):

I had the same problem:
The reason of `"Received unregistered task of type.."` was that celeryd service didn't find and register the tasks on service start (btw their list is visible when you start
 `./manage.py celeryd --loglevel=info` ).

These tasks should be declared in `CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", )` in settings file.
If you have a special `celery_settings.py` file it has to be declared on celeryd service start as `--settings=celery_settings.py` as digivampire wrote.

Comment: Thanks, I actually had the issue because I started celery using ~/path/to/celery/celeryd instead of using the manage.py command!

Answer (score 49):

```
app = Celery('proj',
             broker='amqp://',
             backend='amqp://',
             include=['proj.tasks'])
```

**please include=['proj.tasks']**
You need go to the top directory, then execute this

```
celery -A app.celery_module.celeryapp worker --loglevel=info
```

not

```
celery -A celeryapp worker --loglevel=info
```

in your celeryconfig.py input imports = ("path.path.tasks",)

**please in other module invoke task!!!!!!!!**

Comment: The `include` param need to be add if you're using relative imports.
I've solved my issue by adding it

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; you need to call the worker from the top dir so that that path in the celery launch command matches the import path in the client.

Comment: I don't understand this at all. is there any change of a code sample or to explain what 'proj.tasks' means? are you giving the root folder name where settings.py is or the app where tasks.py is held?

Comment: theres no code sample to explain what to put in celeryconfig.py

Answer (score 42):

Whether you use `CELERY_IMPORTS` or `autodiscover_tasks`, the important point is the tasks are able to be found and the name of the tasks registered in Celery should match the names the workers try to fetch.

When you launch the Celery, say `celery worker -A project --loglevel=DEBUG`, you should see the name of the tasks. For example, if I have a `debug_task` task in my `celery.py`.

```
[tasks]
. project.celery.debug_task
. celery.backend_cleanup
. celery.chain
. celery.chord
. celery.chord_unlock
. celery.chunks
. celery.group
. celery.map
. celery.starmap
```

If you can't see your tasks in the list, please check your celery configuration imports the tasks correctly, either in `--setting`, `--config`, `celeryconfig` or `config_from_object`.

If you are using celery beat, make sure the task name, `task`, you use in `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` matches the name in the celery task list.

Comment: This was very helpful. The name of the task needs to match the the 'task' key in your CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE

Comment: *The important point is the tasks are able to be found and the name of the tasks registered in Celery should match the names the workers try to fetch. * Good point!!!

Comment: This is the correct answer. Your task name in the BEAT_SCHEDULER should match whatever shows up on the list of autodiscovered tasks. So if you used `@task(name='check_periodically')` then it should match what you put in the beat schedule, IE: `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'check_periodically': {
        'task': 'check_periodically', 'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1)
    }`

Answer (score 30):

I also had the same problem; I added

```
CELERY_IMPORTS=("mytasks")
```

in my `celeryconfig.py` file to solve it.

Comment: Note that this should be a list or a tuple: `CELERY_IMPORTS = ['my_module']`

Comment: This did it for me

Answer (score 15):

What worked for me, was to add explicit name to celery task decorator. I changed my task declaration from `@app.tasks` to `@app.tasks(name='module.submodule.task')`

**Here is an example**

At first my task was like:

```
# tasks/test_tasks.py
@celery.task
def test_task():
    print("Celery Task  !!!!")
```

I changed it to :

```
# tasks/test_tasks.py
@celery.task(name='tasks.test_tasks.test_task')
def test_task():
    print("Celery Task  !!!!")
```

This method is helpful when you don't have a dedicated tasks.py file to include it in celery config.

Comment: This also worked for me, but not if I indicated the full path in the `name` kwarg, but only if I just copied the name, so just `celery.task(name='test_task')`. Stupid, but it worked. Trying to figure out why

Comment: Also worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

Using --settings did not work for me. I had to use the following to get it all to work:

```
celery --config=celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO
```

Here is the celeryconfig file that has the CELERY_IMPORTS added:

```
# Celery configuration file
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True

CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks",)
```

My setup was a little bit more tricky because I'm using supervisor to launch celery as a daemon.

Answer (score 11):

For me this error was solved by ensuring the app containing the tasks was included under django's INSTALLED_APPS setting.

Comment: Also, the tasks needed to be accessible from <app>/tasks.py

Answer (score 7):

In my case the issue was, my project was not picking up `autodiscover_tasks` properly.

In `celery.py` file the code was for getting `autodiscover_tasks` was:

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

I changed it to the following one:

```
from django.apps import apps
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: [n.name for n in apps.get_app_configs()])
```

Best wishes to you.

Comment: Ok, it does work, but why? btw thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem mysteriously crop up when I added some signal handling to my django app.  In doing so I converted the app to use an AppConfig, meaning that instead of simply reading as `'booking`' in `INSTALLED_APPS`, it read `'booking.app.BookingConfig'`.

Celery doesn't understand what that means, so I added, `INSTALLED_APPS_WITH_APPCONFIGS = ('booking',)` to my django settings, and modified my `celery.py` from

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

to

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(
    lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS + settings.INSTALLED_APPS_WITH_APPCONFIGS
)
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem running tasks from Celery Beat. Celery doesn't like relative imports so in my `celeryconfig.py`, I had to explicitly set the full package name:

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
   'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'full.path.to.add',
        'schedule': 30.0,
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}
```

Comment: I wish the celery docs had more examples with full package names. After seeing full.path.to.add in this answer, I found out I did not need the imports. I knew the solution was simple, and just needed to have a better example of the app.conf.beat_schedule.

Answer (score 4):

Try importing the Celery task in a Python Shell - Celery might silently be failing to register your tasks because of a bad import statement.

I had an `ImportError` exception in my tasks.py file that was causing Celery to not register the tasks in the module. All other module tasks were registered correctly.

This error wasn't evident until I tried importing the Celery task within a Python Shell. I fixed the bad import statement and then the tasks were successfully registered.

Comment: This was my case too. Had a missing import. Problem is celery just fails silently.

Answer (score 3):

This, strangely, can also be because of a missing package. Run pip to install all necessary packages:
`pip install -r requirements.txt`

`autodiscover_tasks` wasn't picking up tasks that used missing packages.

Comment: I had a similar issue.  I think what happens is an exception during import causes parts of the auto-discovery to not complete.

Comment: Ahh yeah, makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem as well, but it is not quite the same, so just FYI.  Recent upgrades causes this error message due to this decorator syntax.

`ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'my_server_check'.`

`@task('my_server_check')`

Had to be change to just

`@task()`

No clue why.

Comment: my decorators look like `@app.task`

Answer (score 2):

I did not have any issue with **Django**. But encountered this when I was using **Flask**. The solution was setting the config option.

`celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=DEBUG --config=settings`

while with Django, I just had:

`python manage.py celery worker -c 2 --loglevel=info`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the apps config in installed apps like this:

```
LOCAL_APPS = [
'apps.myapp.apps.MyAppConfig']
```

Then in your config app, import the task in ready method like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.myapp'

    def ready(self):
        try:
            import apps.myapp.signals  # noqa F401
            import apps.myapp.tasks
        except ImportError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 2):

did you include your tasks.py file or wherever your async methods are stored?

```
app = Celery('APP_NAME', broker='redis://redis:6379/0', include=['app1.tasks', 'app2.tasks', ...])
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem, my 'task' is under a python package named 'celery_task'，when i quit this package,and run the command `celery worker -A celery_task.task --loglevel=info`. It works.

Comment: This actually works, setting the module/package name

Answer (score 1):

As some other answers have already pointed out, there are many reasons why celery would silently ignore tasks, including dependency issues but also any syntax or code problem.

One quick way to find them is to run:

```
./manage.py check
```

Many times, after fixing the errors that are reported, the tasks are recognized by celery.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into this kind of error, there are a number of possible causes but the solution I found was that my celeryd config file in /etc/defaults/celeryd was configured for standard use, not for my specific django project. As soon as I converted it to the format specified in the [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#example-django-configuration), all was well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me to add this line to /etc/default/celeryd

```
CELERYD_OPTS="-A tasks"
```

Because when I run these commands:

```
celery worker --loglevel=INFO
celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=INFO
```

Only the latter command was showing task names at all.

I have also tried adding CELERY_APP line /etc/default/celeryd but that didn't worked either.

```
CELERY_APP="tasks"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue with PeriodicTask classes in django-celery, while their names showed up fine when starting the celery worker every execution triggered:

KeyError: u'my_app.tasks.run'

My task was a class named 'CleanUp', not just a method called 'run'.

When I checked table 'djcelery_periodictask' I saw outdated entries and deleting them fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that one of our programmers added the following line to one of the imports:

```
os.chdir(<path_to_a_local_folder>)
```

This caused the Celery worker to change its working directory from the projects' default working directory (where it could find the tasks) to a different directory (where it couldn't find the tasks).

After removing this line of code, all tasks were found and registered.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my two cents for my case with this error...

My path is `/vagrant/devops/test` with `app.py` and `__init__.py` in it.

When I run `cd /vagrant/devops/ && celery worker -A test.app.celery --loglevel=info` I am getting this error.

But when I run it like `cd /vagrant/devops/test && celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=info` everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Celery doesn't support relative imports so in my celeryconfig.py, you need absolute import.

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        'add_num': {
            'task': 'app.tasks.add_num.add_nums',
            'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10),
            'args': (1, 2)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An additional item to a really useful list.

I have found Celery unforgiving in relation to errors in tasks (or at least I haven't been able to trace the appropriate log entries) and it doesn't register them.  I have had a number of issues with running Celery as a service, which have been predominantly permissions related.

The latest related to permissions writing to a log file.  I had no issues in development or running celery at the command line, but the service reported the task as unregistered.

I needed to change the log folder permissions to enable the service to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents

I was getting this in a docker image using alpine. The django settings referenced `/dev/log` for logging to syslog. The django app and celery worker were both based on the same image. The entrypoint of the django app image was launching `syslogd` on start, but the one for the celery worker was not. This was causing things like `./manage.py shell` to fail because there wouldn't be any `/dev/log`. The celery worker was not failing. Instead, it was silently just ignoring the rest of the app launch, which included loading `shared_task` entries from applications in the django project

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was because one container created files in a folder that were mounted on the host file-system with docker-compose.

I just had to do remove the files created by the container on the host system and I was able to launch my project again.

> sudo rm -Rf foldername

(I had to use sudo because the files were owned by the root user)

Docker version: 18.03.1

Answer (score 0):

If you use `autodiscover_tasks`, make sure that your `functions` to be registered stay in the `tasks.py`, not any other file. Or celery can not find the `functions` you want to register.

Use `app.register_task` will also do the job, but seems a little naive.

Please refer to this official specification of `autodiscover_tasks`.

```
def autodiscover_tasks(self, packages=None, related_name='tasks', force=False):
    """Auto-discover task modules.

    Searches a list of packages for a "tasks.py" module (or use
    related_name argument).

    If the name is empty, this will be delegated to fix-ups (e.g., Django).

    For example if you have a directory layout like this:

    .. code-block:: text

        foo/__init__.py
           tasks.py
           models.py

        bar/__init__.py
            tasks.py
            models.py

        baz/__init__.py
            models.py

    Then calling ``app.autodiscover_tasks(['foo', bar', 'baz'])`` will
    result in the modules ``foo.tasks`` and ``bar.tasks`` being imported.

    Arguments:
        packages (List[str]): List of packages to search.
            This argument may also be a callable, in which case the
            value returned is used (for lazy evaluation).
        related_name (str): The name of the module to find.  Defaults
            to "tasks": meaning "look for 'module.tasks' for every
            module in ``packages``."
        force (bool): By default this call is lazy so that the actual
            auto-discovery won't happen until an application imports
            the default modules.  Forcing will cause the auto-discovery
            to happen immediately.
    """
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the correct path to the file tasks

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
'send-task': {
    'task': 'appdir.tasks.testapp',
    'schedule': crontab(minute='*/5'),  
},
```

}

Answer (score 0):

when running the celery with "celery -A conf worker  -l info" command all the tasks got listed in log like i was having 
. conf.celery.debug_task
 i was getting the error because I was not giving this exact task path.
So kindly recheck this by copying and pasting exact task id.

Answer (score 0):

```
app = Celery(__name__, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER'], 
backend=app.config['CELERY_BACKEND'], include=['util.xxxx', 'util.yyyy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem lies in THE FIRST LINE of the output you provided in your question: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/loaders/default.py:64: NotConfigured: No 'celeryconfig' module found! Please make sure it exists and is available to Python.
  "is available to Python." % (configname, )))`. Without the right configuration Celery is not able to do anything.

Reason why it can't find the celeryconfig is most likely it is not in your PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue (put it inside your create_app() function):

```
celery.conf.update(app.config)

class ContextTask(celery.Task):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with app.app_context():
            return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

celery.Task = ContextTask
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Docker, like said @ [here](https://www.oscaralsing.com/resolving-celery-received-unregistered-task-of-type-error/) will kill your pain.

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Comment: If you are using docker or docker-compose this is the answer.  Re-build, for some reason, it doesn't work quite right. I have my suspicions why, but not the time to explore them.  Not just restart, rebuild.

Comment: Probably, your app context and celery worker's context don't match. Using celery with 3 different frameworks taught me the real reason. :D

Comment: This also stops *all* docker containers...

Answer (score 0):

For me, **restarting the broker** (Redis) solved it.

---

The task already showed up correctly in Celery's task list and all relevant Django settings and imports worked fine.

My broker was running before I wrote the task, and restarting Celery and Django alone didn't solve it.

However, stopping Redis with Ctrl+C and then restarting it with `redis-server` helped Celery to correctly identify the task.

Answer (score 0):

This error was encountered because Celery did not find the config.
As of 2024, I got it solved by doing the following. I added the following settings to my config in my celeryconfig.py.

```py
broker_url = 'redis:localhost:6379/0'
result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
task_serializer = 'json'
result_serializer = 'json'
imports = ("src.v1.tasks",)
broker_connection_retry_on_startup =True
```

I finally ran my celery app with

```
celery -A runserver.celery --config=celeryconfig worker --loglevel=INFO
```

note that I am pointing to where my config is located using the --config option. Also, I am running my app by getting the module runserver.py which has my celery object. the `imports` settings will point to where my tasks are located, making it easy for Celery to locate them.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the wrong task name had already been persisted by celery beat... was still early enough for me to nuke everything.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting same kind of error in Flask when I was running the server using `python app.py`. In order to solve it, I ran the server using `flask run`

Answer (score -1):

**After searching for wholeday, finally got working after cleaning .pyc files**

```
py3clean .
```