# Celery not finding/using celeryconfg

Tags: python, django, celery

My google-fu must not be up to snuff this morning because I am having trouble finding information why Celery is not finding my celeryconfig file.  There's nothing in the celery log.  The settings I have in celeryconfig just don't seem to be taking effect.  I'm using Django 1.7.6, Celery 3.1.17 and my project & app are running in a virtualenv.  The app is hosted by Apache and wsgi.

I'm using the celeryd script linked to on github from the celery documentation.  Here is my /etc/default/celery with comments removed:

```
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"
CELERY_BIN="/home/celery/.virtualenvs/reporting/bin/celery"
CELERY_APP="main"

CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/celery/dev/reporting"

CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"

CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1

CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="celeryconfig"
```

As you can see, I have CELERYD_CHDIR set to my project directory (the one with manage.py in it).  Here below I've pasted the output of pwd and ls showing the file in that directory:

```
(reporting)celery@wb-devel:~/dev/reporting$ pwd
/home/celery/dev/reporting
(reporting)celery@wb-devel:~/dev/reporting$ ls
celeryconfig.py  csv_output  manage.py  reports.xml
celeryd          main        reporting  requirements.txt
```

The file is readable by all.

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769496/celery-received-unregistered-task-of-type-run-example) suggests explicitly setting the celeryconfig like so: `--settings=celeryconfig` but I'm not sure where to explicitly set that (in /etc/init.d/celeryd?), and still, I would like to do things the right way by using the setting in /etc/default/celeryd to point to celeryconfig

One last thing.  In my celery.py file I have the following set:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'reporting.settings')

app = Celery('main.celery',
          broker='amqp://',
          backend='amqp://',)

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

So how do I get Celery to find my celeryconfig?  Might it be because celeryconfig is not on my python path?  I can't see how that is the case because I have CELERYD_CHDIR set, and also, in my apache config, I have python-path set:  `WSGIDaemonProcess web-reports python-path=/home/celery/dev/reporting:/home/celery/.virtualenvs/reporting/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are mixing up the configuration for standalone vs. Django-based celery.

In general when you use celery as a standalone Python project, then you create a `celeryconfig.py` module. This is shown in [First Steps with Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#configuration) and the key line is: `app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')`

However, when integrating with Django you typically put the configuration values directly in the standard Django `settings.py` module. This variation is shown in [First steps with Django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#first-steps-with-django) and the key line changes to: `app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')`

Since you are telling celery to load configuration from the Django settings module, perhaps you just need to move your values to that file.