# Celery + Flask seperate containers, ERROR/MainProcess Received unregistered task

Tags: docker, flask, rabbitmq, containers, celery

I have set up rabbitmq, flask, and celery-workers in different containers.
No matter what I try, celery keeps complaining about an unregistered task.

Here is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import os
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=os.getenv('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND', 'rpc://'),
        broker=f"pyamqp://{os.getenv('RABBITMQ_USER', 'guest')}:{os.getenv('RABBITMQ_PASS', 'guest')}@{os.getenv('RABBITMQ_HOST')}:{os.getenv('RABBITMQ_PORT')}"
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

app = Flask(__name__)
celery = make_celery(app)

@celery.task(name='background_task')
def background_task(notification_url):
    # Your task implementation
    return 'Task completed successfully!'

@app.route('/start-task', methods=['POST'])
def start_task():
    data = request.json
    notification_url = data.get('notification_url', '')
    task = background_task.delay(notification_url)
    return jsonify({"job_id": task.id, "status": "started"}), 202

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I am pretty sure this is because I am not including the `include` setting in my celery config. But its not clear to me if I need to or how to. Or importing the module container the task (as the error says).

I got separate rabbitmq and celery containers working with a simple app + celeryconfig + tasks.py following [this guide](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/next-steps.html#next-steps)
But how do I include my tasks, if they are not in a separate file?

The [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/celery/) is not clear to me either if they are creating an example with separate containers or not.

I already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513813/celery-rabbitmq-running-as-docker-containers-received-unregistered-task-of-ty) which leads to other similar posts. This was not helpful, as it states the obvious but does not provide examples on how to accomplish importing my tasks into the celery-workers.

How do I configure my backend-api container to use the celery-workers container and the rabbitmq container for async work?