# Celery-beat: why it doesn't work in Django?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

Task itself works well(run asynchronously), but when I trying using `celery beat` it doesn't work.

I followed http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#beat-custom-schedulers.

This is my `django` project structure:

```
.
. 
├── clien
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── management
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── commands
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── crawl_clien.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tasks
│   │   ├── __init__.py           ## ==> code
│   │   └── crawl_clien_task.py   ## ==> code
│   ├── templates
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py     ## ==> code
│   ├── celery.py       ## ==> code
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── partials
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── base.py 
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
.
.
```

Only `clien` is registered in `app`. Here are the codes:

**config/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery('chois_crawler')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'my_task': {
        'task': 'tasks.crawl_clien_task',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
    },
}
```

**config/__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**clien/tasks/crawl_clien_task.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task, Celery
from clien.management.commands import crawl_clien

@shared_task
def crawl_clien_task():
    print("hi")
```

**clien/tasks/__init__.py**

```
from .crawl_clien_task import *
```

It doesn't work...

It showed error :

```
[2017-05-02 09:58:00,027: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'tasks.crawl_clien_task'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
b'[[], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (77b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/envs/chois_crawler/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 559, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'tasks.crawl_clien_task'
```

So I choose the other way:

**config/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('chois_crawler')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**tasks/crawl_clien_task.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task
from celery.schedules import crontab
from config.celery import app

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(minute='*/5'),
        crawl_clien_task(),
        name="hi",
    )

@shared_task
def crawl_clien_task():
    print("hi")
```

But it doesn't work, either!

What's wrong with it?

Comment: restart worker and beat then you will not get this error.

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool I did restart on both ways but still didn't work

Comment: did you added tasks in setting file?

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool What do you mean 'add task in settings file' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include tasks as

```
'appname.tasks.crawl_clien_task',
```

So

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'my_task': {
        'task': 'clien.tasks.crawl_clien_task',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
    },
}
```

Comment: Does the fact that  `clien` is registered in `INSTALLED_APP` but `config` not be matter?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769496/celery-received-unregistered-task-of-type-run-example

Comment: Try with removing `namespace='CELERY'` from celery.py

Comment: If I remove `namespace='CELERY'`, it shows an error : `[2017-05-02 20:10:22,256: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 61] Connection refused.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...` even though I use `redis` as message queue

Comment: Oh I got answer from link you gave... It should have been `clien.tasks.crawl_clien_task.crawl_clien_task`....T_T